# Selecting Nearest Date and exact date in same query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to execute a query to obtain values. I have two tables.

`Table 1` has the following columns (`RowID`, `PercentValue`, `TimeStamp`).

`Table 2` has the following columns (`RowID`, `Elc`, `TotalElc`, `LbsPerHour`, `TotalLbs`, `Shift`, `Timestamp`).

`Table 1` has the ‘`PercentValues`’ column that is important to me. It gets changed once every 6 months, sometimes once a month, but rarely. A new record with a new value and a new timestamp is inserted when this happens.

`Table 2` has values being entered three times a day. Those values are inserted via a dashboard and the following columns get inserted (`Elc`, `TotalElc`, `LbsPerHour`, `TotalLbs` and `Shift`) The `RowID` is auto incrementing and a GetDate() is used for the ShiftTimeStamp)

I need to query values from table 2 based on date and insert them into a new table 3. So if I query one month ago, it’s easy to do this to table 2 since I can match it with an exact date since I have records every day. With table 2, I have few records.

I need the `PercentValue` from `table 1` to multiply by the `TotalElc` in order to give me a `PercentElc`. But I need the `PercentValue` to fall in between the nearest date I selected in the dashboard. If `table 1` has a `PercentVaule` of .20 and a `timestamp` of 7/7/2014 and another `PercentValue` of .30  with a `timestamp` of  7/20/14 and if I query to ask the for the values in `table 2` on 7/10/2014; I should expect to retrieve the `PercentValue` of .2 from `table 1`.

If there is more than one entry prior to 7/10/2014; then the `PercentValue` should be the nearest one to the date Im querying. Here is my code. I am not sure how to code this properly. Any help is most appreciated. Thank you .

```
select  b.ELC, b.TotalElc * a.PercentValue as PercentElc, 
b.LbsPerCase, b.TotalLbs,Shift,  b.ShiftTimeStamp 
from Table1 a, Table2 b, 
where b.ShiftTimeStamp= ‘{0}’  and b.Shift = ‘{1}’
```

‘{0}’ is the parameter I am passing from the dashboard to select the values based off date and ‘{1}’ is the shift ( based on 1,2,3)

Comment: So "nearest" is strictly prior?  What happens when the day you're asking about for `table1` has an update _during_ entries for `table2`?  Do you have 2 different values for that day, or only one (is it based on your querying date, or the timestamp stored)?  Can we get sample starting data and desired results, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CTE's to look up the PercentValue corresponding to the nearest Timestamp, as below:

**EDIT**:

If the nearest `Table1.Timestamp` entry must be prior to `Table2.Timestamp`, then the query becomes much simpler, as below:

```
with time_diff as
(
  select t2.Timestamp t2_ts, max(t1.Timestamp) diff_ts
  from Table1 t1 
  inner join Table2 t2 on t1.Timestamp < t2.Timestamp
  group by t2.Timestamp
)
select 
  a.ELC, 
  a.TotalElc * b.PercentValue as PercentElc, 
  a.LbsPerHour, 
  a.TotalLbs,
  a.Shift , 
  a.TimeStamp 
from Table2 a
INNER JOIN time_diff td ON a.Timestamp = td.t2_ts
INNER JOIN Table1 b ON b.Timestamp = td.diff_ts
--ORDER BY a.RowID
WHERE a.TimeStamp= ‘{0}’ and a.Shift = ‘{1}’;
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a5289/19)</kbd>

Otherwise, if the nearest Timestamp from Table1 could be earlier or later than the Timestamp in Table2, then the following query could be used.

```
with time_diff as
(
  select t2.Timestamp t2_ts, t1.PercentValue t1_PercentValue, abs(DATEDIFF(ss, t1.Timestamp, t2.Timestamp)) diff_ts
  from Table1 t1 cross join Table2 t2
),
percentvalues as
(
  select
    td1.t2_ts,
    td1.t1_PercentValue
  from
  time_diff td1
  inner join
  (
    select t2_ts, min(diff_ts) min_diff_ts
    from time_diff
    GROUP BY t2_ts
  ) td2
  ON td1.t2_ts = td2.t2_ts and td1.diff_ts = td2.min_diff_ts
)
select 
  a.ELC, 
  a.TotalElc * pv.t1_PercentValue as PercentElc, 
  a.LbsPerHour, 
  a.TotalLbs,
  a.Shift , 
  a.TimeStamp 
from Table2 a
INNER JOIN percentvalues pv ON a.Timestamp = pv.t2_ts
--ORDER BY a.RowID
WHERE a.TimeStamp= ‘{0}’ and a.Shift = ‘{1}’;
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a5289/10)</kbd>